# Cannot get Java split function working with regular expression

Tags: android, regex

I have a datetime string of the form YYYYDDMMHHSS that I want to split into its constituent parts.

From my understanding of regular expressions (based on Perl and Javascript) I was under the impression that the following should work:-

```
String dt[] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("datetime")).split("(\\d\\d\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)");
```

where c is a single entry cursor. But it doesn't.

I've searched around SO and Google generally but, although there are examples of split they are just splitting on a single character.

How can I split out the date time into its constituent parts?

Comment: while regex solution will work, it is better to use `SimpleDateFormat` for working with dates

Answer (score 0):

You can match groups with this regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "200426122313";;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)(\\d\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
}
```

then get output:

```
2004
26
12
23
13
```

etc. The parentheses in regex ara a capturing groups, which capture a fragments of text, you want to extract.

You can also split string with:

```
(?<=^\d{4}|^\d{6}|^\d{8}|^\d{10})
```

like in:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "200413122323";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split("(?<=^\\d{4}|^\\d{6}|^\\d{8}|^\\d{10})")));
}
```

to get:

```
[2004, 13, 12, 23, 23]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Sorry - missed your reply to my comment.  Short answer is that I didn't try it as I achieved the same end result in a different way which better suited the application.  However, for the future, I now know what to do and will do what you suggest next time I need to parse a string. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse it with:

```
Date date;    
String dtStart = "YYYYDDMMHHSS";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMMHHss");  //mm -> minutes??
    try {
        date = format.parse(dtStart);
        System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Again, thanks for a quick reply. As with my earlier comment I only need to do this once and so date formating also seemed to be overkill.